# C: Saving specified files with unique extensions

Tags: security, encryption, file-extension, file-type

I'm actually curious on this one.

Hypothetically, let's say I wanted to make a notepad program, so the user can make documents. The user can put in anything s/he desired without a limit.

For privacy so only that program opens it, can I use a specific (undesigned) extension for the program? E.g. Save the file as: "test.abcz". If that's possible, can other default programs (word, notepad) open and see the contents?

I was thinking of designing a notepad based application. It sounds fairly simple, and I think it could assist in my learning of some basics of C.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If the file contains text, any program that can read a text file can read it.  Extensions will not prevent that.  For that matter, really any program that can open a file can open any file, regardless of extension, the contents just might not make sense to it if they are in a different format than expected.  Bottom line, extensions really mean nothing other than a UI and what program runs when you double click them.

Comment: Extensions don't really do anything, they are just a hint to the OS what program to use to open it, and to the programs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make the content of a document unreadable by another software is to apply some sort of transformation on it (cryptography) that could be decoded only by your software, or by a equivalent software that uses the same crypto algorithm as long you have a "key".

The file extension is just a hint to the file manager so it can open a software associated by it, but nothing stops to either manually choose the software or to attempt to open the file directly in the application.

If do you want to train a little, you can try to implement a notepad that saves the file with a ROT13 algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions have nothing to do with the ability to read content.

They are simply a way to tell the operating system how the file **should** be accessed, or what is the **stated** (not **real**) format of the file.

You can test this yourself by renaming a text document to `something.mp3` and viewing the content in notepad.

If the content can be understood by the program - the program can open it. So text files can be viewed by many different editors, but they can't "understand" `.mp3` files (well, usually). Media files can by used my media players, but not by editors, and so on...

What you may consider is encrypting the content when serializing the data (saving the file), so no other program can open it (at least not easily).

Comment: I want to add that obfuscation is not security. I think it applies in OP's case.

Comment: What do you mean by obfusctaion? Encryption, which I brought up, can be anything from requiring a password when the program starts, and deciphering a complex encryption, to a simple Caesar-Cipher that shifts characters in the alphabet.

Comment: Yeah I am not attacking your answer or anything. I'm just saying that OP should be aware that obfuscation - trying to hide sensitive information in "clever" ways without encryption - is not the way someone should deal with an application of that nature. Your answer covers everything else that (s)he may need to know.

Answer (score 0):

In a technical sense, yes.

For instance, even .exe files can be read (not that it makes sense):

```
1. Rename to .txt from .exe
2. Open in notepad.exe
```

Realistically, the privacy of the data is ensured unless it is blatantly obvious format (plain-text)

An extension is a way to identify a program to the system and the actual program, not to the end-user.